# Create User Profile for external Users in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: user-profile

I have 20,000 external Users, they don't have domain account.  How can i create User Profiles for them in SharePoint 2010 ? Is there any way to create them without adding them to domain ?

Comment: How are you storing these users?

Comment: My external users are in DB2 database.

Comment: If you can make a direct connection from SharePoint to the DB2 server, this isn't that difficult to build a timer job and synchronize that way.  I've done it for AD LDS and haven't run into any issues.

Comment: Thank you for the response Trevor.  So in your case, while creating UserProfile what did you put account Name ? In my case, i don't have any account name(domain\userid) ? Just i do have only email (gmail,yahoo or etc).

Comment: The attribute I leverage is 'mail' from AD LDS.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually create user profiles from the "Manage User Profiles" screen in Central Administration (though for 20,000 you'd likely want to automate it with PowerShell.

All profiles have to be associated with "an account", but that account doesn't have to be an AD account. How are your external users authenticating? As an example, if you're using claims/FBA, with a SQL database containing the user accounts for your external users, you should be able to create a user profile using the claim provider and account.

In order for it to work correctly, you'll have to make sure you've properly completed the web.config changes for STS and CA on the Central Administration server, not just on the WFE(s).

Comment: Sorry i have to create User Profiles programatically, not manually.  My External Users are Authenticating using "SiteMinder" as a TIP(Trusted Identity Provider).  My external users are not holding any account, they use their personal email to login into sharepoint.

Comment: According to the SiteMinder documentation, there is no support for profile import through SiteMinder. I'd think your only course of action would be to use SharePoint's built in UPS capability leveraging BCS to connect to your user store database and pull the profile information in.

Comment: BCS can only append, not create, User Profiles.

Comment: Correct. You'd have to create the profiles first, but you should be able to script the initial creation through PowerShell as I originally noted.